# Does normality of a subgroup imply it has index 2?

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

I know that if $G$ is a group, $N < G$, then the condition that $|G:N|=2$ implies that$ N$ is normal in $G$. But what about the converse if we know that $N$ is normal in $G$ does that then imply that the index of $N$ in $G$ is $2$ ?

*For some context from the author of this MSE question, [see this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3053185/does-normality-of-a-subgroup-imply-it-has-index-2/3053189#comment6294542_3053185):*

> @DietrichBurde I worked through another example actually where H is normal in G if the index of H in G is the smallest prime in p because then letting G act on H by right multiplication will induce an embedding in Sp and as G acts transitively we know p divides the image which implies the core of H and H itself are the same so therefore H must be normal in G – can'tcauchy

Comment: Hint 1:   every subgroup of an abelian group is normal.  Hint 2:   the identity element is a normal subgroup of every group (abelian or not).

Comment: Hint. The subgroup containing just the identity is normal.

Comment: Whoever voted to close, would you mind explaining how this question is off topic ?

Comment: @DietrichBurde I worked through  another example actually where H is normal  in G if the index  of H in G is the smallest prime in p because then letting G act on H by right multiplication will induce an embedding in $S_p$ and as G acts transitively we know p divides the image which implies the core of H and H itself are the same so therefore H must be normal in G

Comment: Very good! So it is really worth to try for yourself. Perhaps now the posted question is somehow obsolete (sounds better than off topic).

Comment: @DietrichBurde certainly ! at least for me . But seems as how a few people have spent some of their time answering it I think I should perhaps leave it up ?. It could maybe come in useful to the next person who has the same question too :) although you are right it turned out to be a rather simple excersise to check for myself, I was just being hasty because it's exam season. It seems as though it's receiving quite negative feedback anyway ( 3 votes to close so far) so regardless it seems destined to be taken down . If that happens thank you everyone for helping me to think about this :)

Comment: Take any abelian group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every group is a normal subgroup of itself.

If you insist that the subgroup is not the group itself, then the subgroup containing only the identity is normal in every group.

If you insist that the subgroup is proper, then consider constructing a group by means of a semidirect product. In particular, [as @egreg points out in the comments below](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3053185/does-normality-of-a-subgroup-imply-it-has-index-2/3053189#comment6294426_3053189), a direct product is easiest.

Comment: ah okay and then that has index 1, so the implication only goes one way . thank you :)

Comment: You're welcome, @can'tcauchy; please don't forget to accept this answer using the checkmark $\checkmark$.

Comment: @Shaun A direct product is much simpler: take a group $G$ of whatever cardinality and a group $H$ of cardinality $n$; then $G\times\{1\}$ is a normal subgroup of $G\times H$ of index $n$.

Comment: @Shaun oh I will , it just said I have to wait a minute or two :). By the way on your final comment about constructing the group from a semi direct product then one of the groups must be normal and the other just a subgroup but in that case ( unless I'm mistaken ) we have that half the group has elements from N right ? in that case the index will be two right ?

Comment: Thank you, @egreg; a semidirect product was the first thing that came to mind, s'all. I'll link to your comment in my answer.

Comment: @Shaun never mind egreg answered my question